# Connect two NSObjectControllers within a multi view OSX Storyboard

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6

I'm using Storyboards for the first time creating a master/detail view for a simple object.

Both view controller items of the split view have their own view & NSObjectControllers. The controller for the table view is a NSArrayController (which shows all instances of the Entity). The controller for the detail view is an NSObjectController, which shows just the selected instance.

When I click an object in the table, I'd like the detail to show up in the detail view. So I believe my goal here is to bind the 'contents' of the detail object controller to the 'selection' of the master array controller. However with storyboards I cannot cross view controller boundaries (can't create the IB 'link'. aka: can't bind cross VC).

Whats the best practice for doing this?

So far all I can think to do is manually set all this up in one of the controllers (either the root controller, window controller or perhaps the master table view controller) - but that seems counterintuitive. That seems to defeat the purpose of being able to lay out this stuff within storyboards in the first place, and my controller of choice would then have to know about the other controller specifically.

I must be missing something!